# Jquery row removing not working for me, How to set it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkbox in the first column of the row with name addedCars[] and I am using this code:

```
$('input[name=addedCars]:checked').closest("tr").remove();
```

in jquery to remove that row whose checkbox is checked, but it does not work for me, also there is no error when I console this line be deleting `remove()` from the end it also shows me an object. What is the error can anyone help?

```js
$('#delAddedCarBtn').click(function() {
  console.log("Button clicked");
  $('input[name=addedCars]:checked').closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-th-block table-danger">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></th>
      <th scope="col"><strong>CarNo</strong></th>
      <th scope="col"><strong>Car Name</strong></th>
      <th scope="col"><strong>Type</strong></th>
      <th scope="col"><strong>Model</strong></th>
      <th scope="col"><strong>SalesPrice</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="carTableBody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-name="undefined" value="undefined" name="addedCars[]"></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td>1720000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-name="undefined" value="undefined" name="addedCars[]"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>2010</td>
      <td>1320000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="delAddedCarBtn">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('input[name^=addedCars]:checked').closest("tr").remove();
```

Comment: ^ matches all the input elements starting with addedCars.. wc

Comment: then this line of code will just not work .. execution of script continues further ..

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```
$('table tr').has('input[name="addedCars"]:checked').remove();
```

or

```
$('input[name="addedCars"]:checked').parents("tr").remove();
```